# Is it possible to access tasks via the Live SDK?

Tags: live-sdk, onedrive

I am looking to write a program that will communicate using the Live SDK to access Tasks.  My reason for wanting to do this is that I would like my program to update the task reminder to a date in the future continually if it is not yet complete.  This will prompt me to complete a task instead of getting the reminder once and forgetting about it.

Before I can do this I need to find out if is possible first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to Outlook tasks, the answer is no.  The closest thing we support is calendars and events on calendar.live.com.

Comment: Oh, that is is disappointing.  Do you know if there any plans for this functionality?